# Importing Python packages in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, import

I am struggling to import Python packages, such as `fuzzywuzzy` or `pandas`, into PyQGIS. Whenever I try to import, through `import pandas` for example, I get `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 2):

I found this guide very useful:

https://landscapearchaeology.org/2018/installing-python-packages-in-qgis-3-for-windows/

One option is through OSGeo4W shell

1. Open OSGeo4W shell through the start menu
2. Write `py3_env` in the shell to print the path of your PyQGIS installation
3. Use `python -m pip install {your package}` to install through pip